# How do I understand the logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I'm facing a problem in understanding the comparison logic involved in this code on line below `arr.indexOf(val)==index)`

```js
var arr = [1,4,5,6,3,2,1,6];

var removedDuplicate = arr.filter((val,index)=> arr.indexOf(val)===index);

console.log(removedDuplicate);
```

Trying to understand logic pls help

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? [`filter`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`indexOf`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns the first index of an element in an array.

Therefore, if calling `indexOf` with the value of an element in the array returns the index that element is at, then this is the first time that this value has occurred. All other elements with the same value have a greater index and are duplicates that can be removed.

Note that it is simpler to remove duplicates by using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) (and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert back to an array):

```js
let arr = [1,4,5,6,3,2,1,6];
let res = [...new Set(arr)];
console.log(res);
```

Comment: You may also have to explain/link to the documentation for the spread syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The main question is:

> Have I seen this item before?

The index is a proper approach to answer this question, as [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) has access to the index and [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) give the first found index of an item.

By having this array with indices and indexOf values this may be obvious.

```
array = [1, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 6];
//       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7    indices
//       0  1  2  3  4  5  0  3    indexOf
```

`indexOf` is a costly function, because it iterate always from start of the array for finding the item and it's index.

Anther approach is just to store seen items and filter by keeping unseen items with an object or [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). The last one works directly without any other funtion/method.